# script don't work on FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins

Plugin's code is(i use this script - http://www.tanabi.com/js/jquery.imagemap.js):

```
if(typeof ev.originalTarget.actualPosX == 'undefined'){
     jQuery.imagemap.ffGetPosition(ev.originalTarget);
}
```

i have an error on Firefox - *ev.originalTarget is undefined*, at 86 line

and my code:

```
jQuery.fn.imagecoords = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        jQuery(this).click(function(ev){
                        //var coords;
            var x = jQuery.imagemap.getEventX(ev);
            var y = jQuery.imagemap.getEventY(ev);
                        jQuery('#x').val(x+4);
                        jQuery('#y').val(y+2);
                        jQuery('#new_point').remove();
                        jQuery('#map').append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="new_point" class="bullet" rel="' + x + '-' + y + '" style="left: ' + x + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px; display: block; ">&nbsp;</a>');
                        return 0;
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `event.target` of jQuery. 
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/#event.target

Comment: how it's help me? i think firefox show error when it can't convert undefined type to needed type... or not?

Comment: Can you give me more details or code in your question? It will help me firgure out what's you prolem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that what jQuery is handing you is NOT the actual event object but some jQuery wrapper object around the real thing.  You probably want `ev.originalEvent.originalTarget` here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if ev.originalTarget is defined before accessing ev.originalTarget.something.

```
if(ev.originalTarget) { 
    if(typeof ev.originalTarget.actualPosX == 'undefined') {
        jQuery.imagemap.ffGetPosition(ev.originalTarget);
    }
}
else {
    // Handle undefined or null originalTarget
}
```

You could also use

```
if (typeof(ev.originalTarget) != 'undefined' && ev.originalTarget != null)
```

instead of

```
if(ev.originalTarget)
```

but if(ev.originalTarget) will be faster.